# How to preserve GA recording the correct user-agent and IP of the user via server-side tracking?

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I want to track transactional data to GA from servers using the Measurement Protocol. However, the challenge is that sending a hit from server-side, will record the user agent and other client specific parameters of the server instead of the client.

I came across many recommendations to use the client id generated by the ga.js along-with the hit from the servers, so that it will be mapped to the same user session. However, I ain't sure if that would also replicate client's user agents and other info with the hit from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned much about your system but if its transnational data i am going to assume that you have information about the user who is preforming the transaction.

The measurement protocol has [two](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#user) parameters that are used to denote a session.  [User Id](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#uid) and [client id](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid).

If you can send the [client id](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#cid) from your website over to your server and then send the hits using that client id it will appear to be the same session.

The last option would be to use [User id](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#uid) both on your website and on the server.  If you have an internal user id for your logged in user then you can just send that with the transactions.  Google analytics will then know its the same user and use that for processing independent of the client id.

Note: The location and language may still be that of the server.  You may want to consider over riding user agent or adding IP address and location using some of the [session control](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#session) parameters as well.

I do have a recommendation for you.  If you are still using ga.js I upgrade to [analytics.js](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/)